# Why does ElasticSearch locates primary and replica shard on the same host?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is a new host added to a existing cluster `test` which triggered the rebalance process.

Two nodes `node-5, node-6` are located in the new physical host.

For each shard, there are only a primary shard and one replica shard.

After rebalance, primary shard-4 and replica shard-4 are relocated in this new host.

Why does these two shard are located in the same host? Why does ES not assign one of the shard to a different physical host?
**It is unsafe because if this host goes down, shard-4 will be lost.**

By the way, when rebalancing, the process was paused and
ES said that `cluster.routing.allocation.same_shard.host` should be set to `false` to allow copies of same shard to be allocated different nodes on the same host.

Comment: I know `cluster.routing.allocation.same_shard.host=false` will result in the two shards relocated in the same node. But why ES not assign one of the shard to a different host but suggests to set this property? And what is the whole process of rebalance on earth?

Comment: To clarify, you have virtual server on a bare metal server. Virtual servers `node-5 and node-6` are located on the same physical server and some index primary and replica shards are allocated on the same physical server

Comment: @MusabDogan yes

Comment: I'll share the method for that soon.

Comment: What do you mean by virtual server? `node-5`, `node-6` are two ES nodes on the same physical server. For example we can use command `elasticsearch -E node.name=node-5` `elasticsearch -E node.name=node-6` to create these two nodes on the same server.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Yes we are talking about the same thing.
`node-5, node-6` are two ES nodes (virtual servers) on the same physical server. Follow the answer I shared you will make it done.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch can't know which virtual server installed on which physical server. But you can define manually one by one on each server via `elasticsearch.yml`

You can use the [cluster-level shard allocation awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#shard-allocation-awareness) for that.
**EXAMPLE: Let's say we have 4 virtual server and 2 physical server. Here is an example `elasticsearch.yml` for data nodes.**

**Step1- Update the elasticsearch yml**

```
data-1 - elasticsearch.yml
node.attr.server: node1

data-2 - elasticsearch.yml
node.attr.server: node1

data-3 - elasticsearch.yml
node.attr.server: node2

data-4 - elasticsearch.yml
node.attr.server: node2
```

**Step2- Restart the Elasticsearch**

**Step3- enable shard allocation awaraness**

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes" : "server"
  }
}
```

Comment: what are node1 node2 above?

Comment: Those are examples. In your scenario they will be node5-6 which shared the same physical server.

Comment: node5,node6 correspond to `data-1, data-2` in your example.

Comment: node.attr.server can be specified with same arbitrary name for nodes on the same server?

Comment: Yes, definitely that is the idea. We will define the same attribute for the nodes on the same server. In that way, Elasticsearch won't allocate the primary and replica shard on the same physical server.